# SELinux preventing write access to files

Tags: rhel, pam, selinux, gdm

I have written a PAM module. This PAM module is loaded by processes gdm-password and gnome-screensaver (found on RHEL 6.4). The pam module wants to write some logs to a db file under user's home directory at /home/USER/appdir/data.db. But SELinux prevents this access. I have verified this by disabling SELinux.

I read somewhere that I can change the FILE_TYPE to allow access but not sure which filetype will work in this case.

```
SELinux is preventing /usr/libexec/gdm-session-worker from lock access on the file /home/USER/.appname/0.db.

*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests  ***************************

If you believe that gdm-session-worker should be allowed lock access on the 0.db file by default.
Then you should report this as a bug.
You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
Do
allow this access for now by executing:
# grep gdm-session-wor /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M mypol
# semodule -i mypol.pp


Additional Information:
Source Context                system_u:system_r:xdm_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
...
```

I have another file to which SELinux prevents access. As suggested I changed the FILE_TYPE to pam_var_run_t and it works. I am trying to find details on this file type and confirm whether I chose the correct file type.

```
SELinux is preventing /usr/libexec/gdm-session-worker from write access on the file /var/cache/mysharedstore/mydatastores.reg.

*****  Plugin catchall_labels (83.8 confidence) suggests  ********************

If you want to allow gdm-session-worker to have write access on the mydatastores.reg file
Then you need to change the label on /var/cache/mysharedstore/mydatastores.reg
Do
# semanage fcontext -a -t FILE_TYPE '/var/cache/mysharedstore/mydatastores.reg'
where FILE_TYPE is one of the following: etc_runtime_t, pam_var_run_t, xdm_var_lib_t, xdm_var_run_t, pcscd_var_run_t, xkb_var_lib_t, anon_inodefs_t, gconf_home_t, xdm_rw_etc_t, user_cron_spool_t, xdm_home_t, xdm_lock_t, pam_var_console_t, cgroup_t, locale_t, var_auth_t, wtmp_t, afs_cache_t, xdm_t, user_fonts_t, user_tmpfs_t, user_tmp_t, xdm_spool_t, xserver_tmpfs_t, fonts_cache_t, xauth_home_t, auth_cache_t, xdm_tmpfs_t, security_t, xserver_log_t, proc_afs_t, faillog_t, puppet_tmp_t, xdm_tmp_t, lastlog_t, xdm_log_t, gnome_home_type, initrc_var_run_t, krb5_host_rcache_t, nfs_t, security_t. 
Then execute: 
restorecon -v '/var/cache/mydatastore/myatastores.reg'...
```